# bias in SVM in a balanced set - effect of sample size?

Tags: svm, libsvm

I have a dataset with many subjects, and for each subject I have 100 samples for an X variable, while Y has exactly 50%/50% cases for label 1/2. I am trying to run cross-validation with SVM and found that accuracies are always below 50% despite the set being balanced.

So I made up the following simulation and changed the sample size (see two figures for 50 and 1000).  Still, I get the same below 50% bias. Changing k has an effect, and increasing the sample size also helps - but this doesn't go away - SVM keeps giving me a mean accuracy below 50%, over samples. Cost doesn't make a difference as well as far as I can tell.

Any thoughts???

Thanks, 
Nitzan

```
library(e1071)

nsamples=100
N=2000
x<-runif(nsamples,0,1)
y<-array(1:2, dim=c(nsamples))
z<-array(0,dim=c(N))

for (i in 1:N){  
x<-x[sample(length(x))] 
y<-y[sample(length(y))]
model=svm(x,y,
          type='C-classification',
          kernel="linear",cross=20)
z[i]=mean(model$accuracies)}

histogram(z,nint=20,xlim=c(0,100))
mean(z)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Figured this one out. The problem was that from some reason svm did not use stratification for cross validation...